# Website shows partial ssl issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-chrome, ssl, https

Website I am working on https://www.recordretrieve.com is displaying following error in Chrome:

```
“Your connection to www.recordretrieve.com is encrypted with 128 bit encryption. 
However this page includes other resources which are not secure. 
These resources can be viewed by others while in transit, 
and can be modified by an attacker to change the look of this page”
```

This is a WordPress website and when I "View Sources" I can see that all images I uploaded to WordPress are http, and I saw 2 external javascript files (generated by plugin I used) are also http.

Question is, would this error caused by the image I uploaded to WordPress? If so, how do I fix this issue?

Or would this error cause by the links to js files?

Or caused by both of them?

Answer (score 1):

I use [WordPress HTTPS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/) on my blog to force HTTPS on everything.

Additionally, you can also set the  WordPress Address (URL) and  Site Address (URL) in the [General Settings Screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_General_Screen) to have the https by default.

When you're writing your posts, you need to check if by default you're inserting the http instead of the https

If all this still causes an issue, you should check your theme and plugins to ensure that they are not forcing the http

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing this plugin to solve the issue: http://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/